# Maintaining server side API urls in Javascript application

Tags: backbone.js, single-page-application

I'm building a modular javascript application (RequireJS/Backbone), and am looking for some advice on best practices for propagating server-side URLs into the JS application for use in client side templating, API requests, etc.

Inject it into the base template that kicks off the Javascript application?
API request specifically for this purpose?

Would love to hear solutions others have used. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render a `<script>` tag in the `body`, define a module and put your URLs there in any way you like.
After that you can require it inside your modules (.js files).

**HTML (e.g. your application layout):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Inline RequireJS define</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="foo-holder"></h1>
        <a id="sign-up-link" href="#"></a>
        <script>
            // This is rendered by your server-side application:
            define('data/config', function(require, exports, module) {
                exports.Url = {
                    HOME: 'https://mysite.com',
                    SIGN_IN: 'https://mysite.com/sign-in',
                    SIGN_UP: 'https://mysite.com/sign-up',
                    LOG_OUT: 'https://mysite.com/log-out'
                };

                exports.foo = 'bar';
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript (somewhere in your module):**

```
// This is somewhere in your JavaScript module
require(['data/config'], function(Config) {
    $('#foo-holder').text(Config.foo);
    $('#sign-up-link')
        .text(Config.Url.SIGN_UP)
        .attr('href', Config.Url.SIGN_UP);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/urNEr/)

---

Another trick could be done with some kind of attribute-binding.

**In your layout:**

```
<a data-url="HOME" href="#">Home</a>
<a data-url="SIGN_IN" href="#">Sign In</a>
<a data-url="SIGN_UP" href="#">Sign Up</a>
<a data-url="LOG_OUT" href="#">Log Out</a>
<script>
    // This is rendered by your server-side application:
    define('data/config', function(require, exports, module) {
        exports.Url = {
            HOME: 'https://mysite.com',
            SIGN_IN: 'https://mysite.com/sign-in',
            SIGN_UP: 'https://mysite.com/sign-up',
            LOG_OUT: 'https://mysite.com/log-out'
        };

        exports.foo = 'bar';
    });
</script>
```

**In your JavaScript file:**

```
// This is somewhere in your JavaScript module
require(['data/config'], function(Config) {
    $('a[data-url]').each(function() {
        var $a,
            urlConstant,
            url;
        $a = $(this);
        urlConstant = $a.data('url');
        url = Config.Url[urlConstant];
        if(url) {
            $a.attr('href', url);
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/GJzrb/)

Comment: Great, this is really close towards the direction I'm going to be using. Just instead of changing the URLs with jQuery later, I will pass the contents of the URL module into the client side templating library I'm using. So I'll have the urls available as {{Config.url.SIGN_IN}} or something like that in my templates.

Comment: Sure, you can pass config into template and use its constants inside it.